# ISP blocking alternative DNS?

Tags: dns

I have an issue where I can't seem to set an alternative DNS than the one my ISP would like me to use. I've tried several options including a pi-hole, just setting DNS differently on my router or on my device to any public available options like 1.1.1.1 or 9.9.9.9 or 8.8.8.8. Device doesn't matter. The result is always the same, the DNS doesn't resolve the moment I change from my ISP DNS.

A potential complication is that my ISP installed a mikrotik device in my house which I have no access to. I've installed my own Asus router behind it and all my devices are connected to that. I can use the Mikrotik by plugging in a LAN cable, I've tried as well, but the DNS issue persist.

Could my ISP block for example port 53 unless it's routed to their own DNS server? Or perhaps it's even setup on the Mikrotik in my house. I can ping the DNS servers previously mentioned and even a telnet to 8.8.8.8 TCP port 53. (But I believe DNS is UDP based?)

Any ideas how to solve this issue besides using a VPN? Can I somehow redirect DNS requests to a different port? Or perhaps get a paid (or free?) service which doesn't use port 53 for DNS traffic? Any input or further troubleshooting advice is very welcome. My ISP is not very responsive, so asking them has not resulted fruitful so far.

Comment: How about changing ISP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could my ISP block for example port 53 unless it's routed to their own DNS server?

Yes. It's just a basic firewall rule, either on the Mikrotik router or on their central firewall higher up. Generally, if *you* can block some packets using a firewall, then your ISP can do the same as well.

If they wanted, they could also easily *redirect* packets to port 53 towards their own DNS server, regardless of where those packets were supposed to go, in the same way as "port forwarding" (DNAT) rules on your router redirect packets.

> Any ideas how to solve this issue besides using a VPN? Can I somehow redirect DNS requests to a different port

Use DoT aka "DNS over TLS", which runs over port 853 instead. (If that's also blocked, use DoH – "DNS over HTTPS" – which uses port 443 exactly like regular HTTPS. They are both identical in terms of security or privacy, only differing in technical factors.)

Some system DNS resolvers (Windows and systemd-resolved) and even web browsers (Firefox) now have built-in support for DoT and/or DoH servers. In other cases you can use a local proxy; for example, it is very likely that Pi-Hole would allow you to enable DoT for the "upstream DNS server".

All of the three public DNS servers you mentioned already support DoT *and* DoH (see the docs for [1.1.1.1](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/encryption/), for [8.8.8.8](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/secure-transports), for [9.9.9.9](https://www.quad9.net/service/service-addresses-and-features/)); there are other public providers supporting these protocols as well (e.g. [DNS.SB](https://dns.sb/dot/) or [SWITCH](https://www.switch.ch/security/info/public-dns/)).

As both DoH and DoT use TLS, they also have the advantage that your ISP cannot intercept or redirect them without you noticing, but be sure to check the DNS service's documentation to find out what DoT "hostname" or DoH "URL template" it recommends you to use – your DoT client will need the hostname for TLS certificate verification.

(Setting up your own DNS resolver server on a VPS somewhere is also an option – it would let you use an alternative port for regular DNS, as well as having your own DNS over TLS and/or HTTPS service. Since a resolver is only a cache, not a database, the resource requirements are minimal.

Finally, it is possible to use a VPN *just* for DNS traffic, although it's more work (and not something you could do with regular commercial VPN apps), but doable if you're into running your own.)

Comment: Very helpful reply, thank you! I see my router supports DoT and need to look into the manual how to set it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: DoT works like a charm. Anytime I revert back to port 53 for DNS I can only use my ISP's DNS servers. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to verify if your ISP blocks alternate DNS servers.

On Windows run :

```
nslookup -debug -type=TXT test.dns.google.com. dns.google.
nslookup -debug -type=TXT -vc locations.dns.google.com. dns.google.
```

On macOS or Linux run :

```
dig -t TXT test.dns.google.com. '@dns.google.'
dig -t TXT +tcp locations.dns.google.com. '@dns.google.'
```

> If the first command's output shows "Thanks for using Google Public
> DNS." your UDP queries are reaching Google Public DNS; if the second
> command's output includes locations.publicdns.goog. your TCP queries
> are reaching Google too.
>
> If the output shows NXDOMAIN then you are reaching another DNS
> resolver. If the output shows a timeout, DNS queries to Google Public
> DNS are blocked. Use the UDP or DNS traceroute commands in the
> following section to see where hijacking or blocking may be happening.

Source : [Google Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/troubleshooting).

You will also find useful information and instruction on bypassing such
practices using DoH in the article
[What Is Encrypted DNS Traffic?](https://heimdalsecurity.com/blog/what-is-encrypted-dns-traffic/)

(I note that an ISP that does such actions is not acceptable in democratic
countries.)

Comment: I live in a country that is doesn't score high on the democratic scale! Thanks for the commands to verify my DNS, very helpful. I've now setup my router to use DoT and also allow DoH traffic.